# How can I store part of the current URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a web app that uses a zip code (passed from the previous page). The URL looks like /location#12345

I am trying to store everything after '#' in a variable to be used in the location finder app.

```
        URL: /locations#12345

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
            queryString = queryString.substring(1);
            var queries = queryString.split("#");
            var myVal;
            for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
            {
                myVal = myVal + queries[i];    
            }
            alert(myVal);
        });
```

I thought alert(myVal) would produce "12345" but it is blank. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: `'blubb#1234'.split('#').pop()` If you are sure that it is always the last one.

Comment: Wow, this worked perfect. I used this line of code: var myVal = document.URL.split('#').pop();

Comment: `document.location.hash` would be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For a single hash `String.split()` is enough:

**Working demo**

```js
const str = '/locations#12345UR';
const hash = str.split('#')[1];
alert(hash);
```